# Flask Blueprint API not working when deployed on Vercel

Tags: python-3.x, flask, vercel

Deploying Flask API on Vercel cloud hosting platform won't work completely.

I tried to follow this instruction on deploying Flask to Vercel https://vercel.com/templates/python/flask-hello-world. Running Vercel CLI with `vercel dev`, it works for the `/` and `/about` routes, but with Flask Blueprint API `api_bp` registered in `api/index.py`, I can't access `/api/*` urls, giving me an Internal Server Error instead.

Could anyone tell me how to edit `vercel.json` so to make Flask Blueprint API accessible?
...or any other way to fix this so I can deploy Flask API with blueprints on Vercel or any other free cloud hosting platforms?

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/api/index"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
import datetime as dt

from apscheduler.events import EVENT_JOB_ERROR
from flask import Flask, current_app, render_template
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler
from scheduler_config import Config
from tracking_utils import error_listener
from api.routes import api_bp
from all_scripts.scripts_utils import refresh_disabled_jobs_file
from api.api_utils import page_links

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True  # required to access flask-apscheduler API

scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)
scheduler.add_listener(error_listener, EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
scheduler.start()

# Register the API blueprint
app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

# disabled_jobs.json needs empty on reboot coz enabled_jobs restarts on reboot.
refresh_disabled_jobs_file()


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello, World!'


@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'About'
```